# Can map on first render but on refresh shows cannot map of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Trying to display content from an API. On first render the information (movie titles) are displayed with no issue. When I refresh it says cannot map undefined.

Heres the code

```
  const [media, setMedia] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}&language=en-GB&page=1&region=GB`
    );
    const data = await res.json();

    return setMedia(data);
  }
  return (
    
      {media &&
        media.results.map((item, index) => <p key={index}>{item.title}</p>)}
)
```

media state is like so:

```
{
page: 1,
results: [
{title: 'The Godfather'},
{title: 'A new hope'}
]
}
```

I'm using nextjs and the data being fetched via getServerSideProps() works fine. This is using vanilla React and doesn't work even though the data returned is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an extra check before your `.map()` usage as the following:

```
{media && media.results &&
        media.results.map((item, index) => <p key={index}>{item.title}</p>)}
```

In this way you are checking if `media.results` has values.

Answer (score 0):

```
{(media?.results || []).map((item, index) => <p key={index}>{item.title}</p>)}
```

Try to add default value for your results array to prevent undifined